# Seemingly unrelated specification in offsetof reference

Tags: c++

I was reading reference of [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) and saw the following:

> Given an object `o` of type type with static storage duration, `&(o.member)` shall be a constant expression and point to a subobject of `o`. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.** Particularly, if member is a static data member, a bit-field, or a member function, the behavior is undefined.

My first question is why would this appear in the reference of offsetof, as I cannot see any obvious relevance of it with offsetof.

Second, regarding the emphasis in above quote, what does "otherwise" mean? Does it mean for object `o` with automatic or dynamic storage duration, `&(o.member)` is undefined? I thought such expression would be legal, am I missing something? Or is it because of the parenthesis?

Comment: For the second part of your question, it's answered in the second part of the quote "Particularly..."

Comment: The (raw, untyped) difference between `&o` and `&(o.member)` is effectively the offset.

Comment: Among other things, a static member has a constant address (`&o`).   Similarly, the address of any non-static member (`&(o.member)`) will also be constant.   The difference between them (`&(o.member) - &o`) is therefore constant.   So this clause is effectively saying that `offsetof(type, member)` is constant.    The otherwise means that, if none of the preceding conditions are true, the behaviour is undefined.   Essentially, it means that there is no specified relationship between `&o` and `&o1` unless `o1` is a subobject of `o`  (i.e. it is not a member, or a member of a member, ...).

Comment: Thanks, folks, I see my problem. I took the **`&(o.member)` shall be a constant expression** for granted for static object. But this clause is a requirement for the macro parameters type and member, which I found in the C standard. Otherwise means if it is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevance is that this is explaining the requirements for `offsetof`. It goes without saying that you can't pass two arbitrary parameters and give meaningful results. So the requirements for `offsetof` are specified in terms of an example. `offsetof` is specified thusly:

```
#define offsetof(type, member) ...
```

The macro's first parameter's name is `type`, its 2nd parameter's name is `member`. With that out of the way:

> Given an object o of type type with static storage duration,...

This is outlining what the requirements are: let's say that you have a `static` object of `o` of type `type` (macro's first parameter), and furthermore:

> &(o.member) shall be a constant expression and point to a subobject of o.

... this says that if, in this situation, you also have `o.member` being a constant expression and referencing some "subobject", a.k.a. member of `o`, which is of type `type`...

... then this is what this macro's requirements are, in order for `offsetof` to give you its specified result.

You ask:

> what does "otherwise" mean?

Here, "otherwise" means anything other than all of the above conditions being met.

Comment: I don't understand why would the requirement of offsetof involves an object, because the parameters of offsetof is just a type and its member. Not to say an object with further storage duration requirement.

Comment: I'm sure there are alternative means of defining formal requirements. This is simply the way whoever wrote that chose to phrase what the requirements are. You say it's just "type and its member", but they chose to frame it in terms of a hypothetical object of the type called `o`, and with `&(o.member`)` being valid C++ code in that case. That says the same thing, but in a somewhat more pedantic manner.

Comment: So **the behavior is undefined** in emphasized part is saying the offsetof expression not the `&(o.member)` is undefined?

Comment: Correct, with "undefined" meaning anything from "the code will not compile and produce a confusing error message that you cannot comprehend" to "the code will compile but will use a random number generator for the returned offset value, and what happens when your code uses it will be up to you to deal with".